# JSON_MODIFY not able to handle special character '/'

Tags: json, sql-server-2016

```
DECLARE @json NVARCHAR(4000)

DECLARE @VAL NVARCHAR(4000)

SET @json = 
N'{
"info":{  
  "type":1,
  "address":{  
    "town":"Bristol",
    "county":"Avon",
    "country":"England"
  },
  "tags":["Sport", "Water polo"]
},
"type":"Basic"
}'


SET @VAL='123'

SELECT @json = JSON_MODIFY(@jSON,'$.type',CONCAT('Metro','/',@VAL))

SELECT @json


SELECT CONCAT ( 'Metro ', '/', @VAL ) AS Result;
```

====================================

JSON_Modify is returning type as - Metro \ /123 But it should return as Metro/123

Comment: OUTPUT for JSON_MODIFY:{      "info":{          "type":1,          "address":{            "town":"Bristol",          "county":"Avon",          "country":"England"        },        "tags":["Sport", "Water polo"]     },     "type":"Metro\/123"  }

Comment: OUTPUT for CONCAT :Metro /123

Comment: Had to use: replace(@json, '\/', '/'); and that solved my problem.